# Building taxonomy Selector

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, views

I'm building a classified website, on which users can create ads using the custom content type I've created. Each ad has a `category` field which a reference to a multilevel taxonomy, and uses the  hierarchical select field type.

When a user creates an ad/classified, I'd like the UI to first ask the user to choose from the the top-level terms of the taxonomy, then from the child terms of what is selected, then the child terms of that, so on so forth.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Multi-level category UI widget]

I've already tried using [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) with [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select), and [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) but neither have worked out so far. I'm trying to create something that's user friendly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please note that questions about _Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided_ are off topic here as they're only likely to be useful to the person asking them. The [help] has more information on what kinds of question to ask here

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.

Comment: I already tried but  it's not help or maybe i didn:t understand the right way to configure it in this way